# Installation CD takes me to a login-screen for Ubuntu with no users to choose from

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, live-cd

I tried to install Ubuntu 11.04 side-by-side with my Windows on my HP Pavillion g6, but it caused me a lot of different troubles.
So I tried to reinstall Ubuntu on all of the disk memory with a live-boot CD, but every time I use the CD it takes me to a login-screen for Ubuntu (with no users to choose from) and wants me to write in a username and a password. From here I get nowhere and now I'm stuck. Should I try to install Ubuntu some other way or does anyone have an idea of what I should do?

Update for answer by Pavlos G:

My problems are many. First off, I left the idea of having Windows side to side with Ubuntu and wanted to install only Ubuntu. So Windows is not really the issue, but the problems I had (or have) were two major ones:

1. Windows would not start. It only said "put in your Windows installation cd" and I think that something went wrong during the partitioning part of the installation.
2. At first, the computer did not won't to start at all which I learned how to fix, but than I got other problems. The computer asked me to install a special device for my graphic card (AMD Radeon HD 6470M) and I did. When I reboot the computer later on Unity, this was gone and Ubuntu had gone back to Gnome. So I figured out because I had nothing on the computer (it's new), I could make a reinstallation instead. ...which now is the problem, but I think your link maybe can fix it.

Comment: installing ubuntu side-by-side - or within windows as a wubi install is the recommended method.  If you can edit your question with what your "troubles" were (what your tried, what you saw) and with as much details of your hardware (such as graphics) then I'm sure we can try to help you further.

Comment: If you're not interested in dual booting with Windows, just make a clean installation of Ubuntu (after all you said that the Windows installation is now broken). The problem with Unity probably has to do with the graphics driver, but we can see that later.

Comment: Yeah know that, but as said from the beginning: I can't get the installation going on. Tried with whats in the link below (leave the fields empty) but it won't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try `ubuntu` as the username with a blank password.

More info can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD#Troubles%20with%20a%20LiveCD).